# How to get a ComboBox to use an Object's toString method instead of setting it as a graphic?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, ellipse

I have a `Station` object that `extends` `javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse`:

```
public class Station extends Ellipse
```

And I am trying to put them into a `javafx.scene.control.ComboBox` and have that `ComboBox` use the `toString()` method of my `Station` objects instead of using them as a graphic.

```
 ComboBox<Station> metroStationComboBox = new ComboBox<>();
 //ADDS A HASHSET OF THE STATIONS
 metroStationComboBox.getItems().addAll(dataManager.getStations());
```

I made a cell factory which will use the `toString()` method when they are not selected, but as soon as you select one, it will take the object in as a graphic.:

```
metroStationComboBox.setCellFactory((ListView<Station> p) -> {
        return new ListCell<Station>(){
            @Override protected void updateItem(Station item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!empty && item != null) {
                    setText(item.toString());
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setText(null);
                }
            }

        };
    });
```

Is there a way to redefine the selection method so that I can have it use the `toString` method of `Station`?

[image]

(The above code has been reduced for clarity)

Comment: You need to call `setButtonCell` too.

Comment: @James_D Oh that was easy. Thank you for the help! If you make an answer to the question I'll mark it as accepted.